# Inside Ajax make Ajax loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops

**What I am trying to do is:**

First Ajax is uploading csv file and gets all the products list. Then on success it goes through loop and calls another ajax which uploads these products.

**Problem:**

When it goes through loop it freezes browser and waits till every product will be uploaded and then it prints out the ID's.

**What I need:**

To get rid of freezing browser and when it could print every ID after every product has been uploaded.

**Code:**

```
var data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', jQuery('#item_data')[0].files[0]);
        data.append('action', 'csv_upload');
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            timeout: 3000,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                jQuery( ".wrap .all" ).html(data.information.length);
                jQuery.each(data.information, function (i, elem) {
                    add_item(elem, i);
                });
                jQuery( "#results" ).append( "<p style='color:green;'>The end!</p>" );
            }
        });

    function add_item(elem, i){
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('action', 'product_upload');
        data.append('file_cont', JSON.stringify(elem));
        jQuery.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                jQuery( "#results" ).append( "<span>"+ data.message +"</span>" );
            }
        });
        jQuery( ".wrap .count" ).html(i+1);
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', jQuery('#item_data')[0].files[0]);
data.append('action', 'csv_upload');
jQuery.ajax({
  url: ajaxurl,
  data: data,
  timeout: 3000,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    jQuery(".wrap .all").html(data.information.length);
    add_item(data.information, data.information[0], 0);
  }
});



function add_item(info, elem, i ) {
  var
    data = new FormData();
  data.append('action', 'product_upload');
  data.append('file_cont', JSON.stringify(elem));
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      if (info.length >= i + 1) {
        jQuery("#results").append("<span>" + data.message + "</span>");
        add_item(info, info[i + 1], i + 1);
        jQuery(".wrap .count").html(i + 1);
      }
    }
  });
  if(info.length == i){
            jQuery( "#results" ).append( "<p style='color:green;'>The End!</p>" );
        }
}
```

you can do it recursively, since setting `async: false` will wait for the request to finish before the next instruction is executed.

UPDATE: removed `async: false`, and added with "The End" message correction.

Comment: Thanks Nijeesh for reply, but thats why I added `async: false` to add_item, because this function uploads only 1 product, because this function is inside the loop.

Comment: if you add `async: false` the browser is gonna freeze till the request is resolved. if you dont want that to happen you can make the success callback of your `add_item` ajax call to call the next iteration of the each loop. 
like a recursive function

Comment: Thanks for full explanation, could you guide me how to make it ? or show any example? thank you!

Comment: i have made a very crude version with `setTimeout` maybe this will clear things up for you https://jsfiddle.net/nijeesh4all/9cks24mq/

Comment: so your code just waits for some time and after that it executes cb() function? I think this not the right answer, because there is no ajax, just waiting for some time and then it executes... What I was thinking is to get some response and execute another item. Is there any smarter way to do this?

Comment: that was just an example for an asyc function. you can replace the setTimout with your ajax call.  ```> i have made a very crude version with setTimeout```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand your example, as I don't get it how it should work.

Comment: give this a try:- https://jsfiddle.net/nijeesh4all/9cks24mq/26/

Comment: with async: false it freezes UI and after that it shows all the ID's it updated. If I remove async: false, it shows message The End and after that it prints ID after ID it updated. How to make that The END message would print in the end of the process not at the beginning ?

Comment: Thank you so much Nijeesh for great guide, now I understood, and made some changes for final code. I removed async: false, because it still freezes the UI.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i should have removed the `async: false` that was unintentional.  just a word of advice please try not to use `async: false' unless its absolute necessary

Comment: yeah correct I will know in the future, thanks again :)